# Can only access 1.9 gb of RAM on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ram

So I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (edit: 64-bit) on my PC. My PC had 4 GB of RAM installed, which the BIOS recognizes. It also displays when I type `uname -m`, so the OS knows it's there. However, according to the system monitor, I have access to 1.9 GB. Unfortunately, my computer's performance seems to be in line with the latter report.

I have tried:
Re-seating my RAM
Flashing my BIOS
Disabling integrated video
Buying new RAM (Bringing me to a total of 8 GB; still only 1.9 are being used)

I saw a similar question that it's an issue that occurs in kernels newer than 2.6.32; is there some way I can downgrade to an older kernel to use all my RAM?

Edit: Here's my BIOS mapping. Note the various "reserved" sections. I'm 90% sure those don't need to be there.

```
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009e7ff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e800-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007d7b2fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007d7b3000-0x000000007d98afff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007d98b000-0x000000007d994fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007d995000-0x000000007dd84fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007dd85000-0x000000007e159fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007e15a000-0x000000007e15afff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007e15b000-0x000000007e360fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007e361000-0x000000007e7fffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec10000-0x00000000fec10fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec20000-0x00000000fec20fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed61000-0x00000000fed70fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed8ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fef00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
```

Comment: I can't deal with you right now, sorry. But here are some ideas : Check if your CPU has PAE // Use `free -h` and `sudo lshw` // What does your BIOS says? maybe your motherboard doesn't support more than 2GB (imo that is not the problem^^) // What does it say when you're on a LiveSession (with CD or USB key) ? // install latest kernel from kernel.org, there might be a bug with your hardware on 3.10 kernel (?).

Comment: `uname -m` only prints the processor/hardware info *(i think...)* - Are you using a PAE kernel? - add is the output of: `</boot/config-$(uname -r) fgrep CONFIG_X86_PAE=`. Also, there is a graphical interface for `lshw` you can use: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lshw-gtk/

Comment: Apologies: to clarify, I do have 64-bit Ubuntu, so PAE shouldn't be the issue. Bios lists my RAM as normal, and outputs a total of 8 gigs spread over 3 sticks.

Comment: Check /var/log/kern.log or `dmesg` and look for the section describing the bios e820 map and add it to your question.

Comment: Your bios is broken; check for an update from your hardware vendor.

Comment: Well great. I already did that, and tried both versions of BIOS available for my motherboard.